# How can I change all existing designator font sizes on PCB in Altium?

Tags: altium, properties

When I select multiple designators and when I select "properties" - only one designator changes. I have same problem with setting other parameters on multiple objects.

How can I change all **existing** designator font sizes on PCB in Altium?

Comment: Do you use 'find similar'? That certainly works for many parameters.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Right click on one designator.

Select "Find Similar Objects".

Set "Object Kind : Text" to "same"
Set "String Type : Designator to "same"

Then "apply".

All designators are now selected.

Use the properties panel to edit the text size of all selected texts.

Comment: Ooops I forgot to mark this as an answer long time ago.